# Pressing launcher icon resumes the App. What intent flags are required for to make this happen?

Tags: android, android-activity

[This is a documented behavior on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#background-foreground):

> Consider for example, the following task flow for a current task (Task
> A) that has three activities in its stack, including two under the
> current activity:
>
> The user uses the Home button or gesture, then starts a new app from the app launcher.
> When the Home screen appears, Task A goes into the background. When the new app starts, the
> system starts a task for that app (Task B) with its own stack of activities.
>
> **After interacting with that app, the user returns Home again and selects the app that
>
> originally started Task A. Now, Task A comes to the foreground—all three activities in its
> stack are intact and the activity at the top of the stack resumes.** At
> this point, the user can also switch back to Task B by going Home and
> selecting the app icon that started that task (or by selecting the
> app's task from the Recents screen).

So this is the scenario where there already exists a task for the App and the user taps on the launcher icon, the task is brought to foreground. As you can contemplate that there is an Intent required to launch activities.

QUESTION: What flags are responsible for resuming the task(top Activity of the task) rather than creating a new instance of the Activity?

Note: If you are thinking `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` then that is supposed to clear out all the activities in the task first and then deliver the Intent to the launcher activity which would be the root activity in the task(through `onNewIntent()`) but that is not what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use launch mode in the manifest. Something like this.

```
        <activity android:name="com.smart.review.BaseActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```